# Visual Studio 2022 lists Automapper which is an incompatible nuget update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Visual Studio lists AutoMapper 11.0.1 in the Nuget packages Updates list when all projects target .NET Framework 4.8, which is incompatible with 11.0.1. Is this normal, or is there an error in my solution configuration, a bug in Visual Studio or something else? When I attempt to install it I get this error - Could not install package 'AutoMapper 11.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: AutoMapper 11.0.1 appears to require .Net Standard 2.1 which is not supported by any version of .Net Framework. You would have to upgrade your projects to at least .Net Core 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @phuzi. That much I know. My question relates to why the update is listed when I can't use it. I'd expect Visual Studio to only show updates I can use.

Comment: No, ASFAIK this information is only available after the full package has been downloaded. Therefore the nuget browser cannot determine that beforehand.